# Swift Package Manager not Importing

Tags: xcode, swift3, swift-package-manager

I am trying to import a framework into swift using the Swift Package manager because a Pod is not available for it. The import does not appear in the project classes and none of its functions are available. I am currently running Swift 3.1 and have done the following in terminal: swift build, swift package generate-xcodeproj, and cleaned the project. Here is my Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:3.1

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/WeirdMath/Scrape.git", majorVersion: 1)
    ]
)
```

I have gotten the following output in terminal:

-Compile Swift Module 'MyPackage' (2 sources)

-note: you may be able to install libxml-2.0 using your system-packager:
brew install libxml2

Is there a way to compile the package further or to install libxml?
Note: the frameworks libxml2.0 & libxml2.2 are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but I'll write here steps I followed to *make it work*:

1. I've created directory for project and called `swift package init
   --type executable`
2. Modified `Package.swift` to reflect yours
3. `swift build` to get:

   > -note: you may be able to install libxml-2.0 using your system-packager: brew install libxml2
4. Called `brew install libxml2`
5. `swift build` again - this time without any warnings
6. `swift package generate-xcodeproj`
7. Opened it in Xcode and added `import Scrape` in `main.swift`

Everything works fine, I guess?

Comment: still at the same issue, terminal keeps giving me "-bash: brew: command not found" when i call brew install libxml2. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Do you have homebrew installed? 

Comment: Ok I installed homebrew successfully and got past the install libxml. Do I need to make a main.swift file or is it the "myprojectname".swift? Or do I need to run a different line of commands?

Comment: Oh do I need to work out of the package instead of the workspace now?

Comment: You should have Sources folder in root directory. If it’s correct for you, there’s should be main.swift. Main file is the starting point of every application - SPM is no exception 

Comment: There is no main.swift

Comment: Just create it! 

Comment: It says No such module 'Scrape' when I open main.swift in the xcworkspace

Comment: `swift build` again... You can also regenerate xcodeproj. Xcode project is just a side effect you can get from SPM. It shouldn’t be your source of truth. What’s important is in Package.swift

Comment: Not sure whats happening. Built and regenerating. Still doesnt recognize it. Here is my main.swift:

Comment: import Scrape

struct Main {
   
    var text = "Hello, World!"
}

Comment: Create new directory for your project, generate it using `swift package init –type executable` and you’ll have whole structure set up correctly.

Comment: Ok now the scrape framework appears in my project but i get 25+ errors about it saying "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group"

Comment: That’s strange... Do you also get them in command line when calling `swift build`? Maybe it’s related to some sort of cache...

Comment: No i dont. Was it supposed to reformat my entire project. The app icon is gone and the project thinks its for mac instead of ios

Comment: Reganerate it every time you change something - just to be sure you’re not missing anything.